# Event Listeners - Entity Column level Listener

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, event-listener

I am new to event listeners, and wondering if there is any solution to only track a column level value changes instead of writing a event listener to see if its an instance of Book and if the price of the book changed.

Ex:

**Table**

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private LocalDate publishingDate;

    @Column
    private Double price;

}
```

In the above table, I just want to know if any changes were done to price of the book, rather than listener being notified of any updates to the entity every time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track changes of a field you need to remeber old value and compare it with new value. Introduce new field `@Transient Double previousPrice`. Intialize it in `@PostLoad` callback method with `price` value. You can than check if it was changed by comparing `price` and `previousPrice` in

1. `@PreUpdate` method (inside entity)
2. when calling `setPrice` method (inside entity)
3. anytime with convenient method `book.isPriceChanged(){ return price!=null && price.equals(previousPrice);}` (outside entity)